# Printing footers using enscript

Tags: bash, printing, text-processing, format-conversion, postscript

I have a working bash script which converts text files to postscript using enscript 1.6.5.90-2 on Kubuntu 14.04.

It does several other things to make the output look better like setting margins, wrapping lines, etc. (which is why I need enscript instead of other simpler printing tools.)

The script currently prints a title in the page header, but now I need a footer too.

Can anybody show me a current *working example* using enscript to produce footer lines?

I see --footer=FOOTER in the man page, but I also see that the default footer height is zero points. I have tried a number of ways to get footers to print. None of them produce any error messages, but they don't print footers either.

I don't have room for everything I want to see in the header alone so I need to put some of it in the footer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that, if you want footers, you have to write a custom hdr file and then select it with the `--fancy-header` option.  I have written one (below) that may work for you.

There is a [nine-year-old bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=344698) on this problem.  The approach in that bug report attempts a more comprehensive solution and requires re-compiling `enscript`.  My approach is not as comprehensive but eliminates the need for a re-compile.

This header file is based on `simple.hdr`.  To use it, copy and paste it into a file called, say, `simple2.hdr`, and, for system-wide use, place it in the directory `/usr/share/enscript`.  For personal use, it can be placed in the `~/.enscript/` directory:

```
% -- code follows this line --
%Format: fmodstr    $D{%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y}
%Format: pagenumstr $V$%

%HeaderHeight: 38
%FooterHeight: 15

/do_header {   % print default simple header

  % Footer
  gsave
    d_footer_x d_footer_y HFpt_h 3 div add translate
    HF setfont

    user_footer_p {
      d_footer_x  d_footer_y moveto user_footer_left_str show

      d_footer_w user_footer_center_str stringwidth pop sub 2 div
      0 moveto user_footer_center_str show

      d_footer_x d_footer_w add user_footer_right_str stringwidth pop sub
      d_footer_y moveto user_footer_right_str show
    } if
  grestore

  % Header
  gsave
    d_header_x d_header_y HFpt_h 3 div add translate
    HF setfont

    user_header_p {
      5 0 moveto user_header_left_str show

      d_header_w user_header_center_str stringwidth pop sub 2 div
      0 moveto user_header_center_str show

      d_header_w user_header_right_str stringwidth pop sub 5 sub
      0 moveto user_header_right_str show
    } {
      5 0 moveto fname show
      45 0 rmoveto fmodstr show
      45 0 rmoveto pagenumstr show
    } ifelse
  grestore

} def
```

Usage is quite simple.  You can then invoke it with something like:

```
enscript --fancy-header=simple2 --header="HEADER" --footer="LEFT|CTR|RIGHT"
```

Note that, although `enscript` supports many character sets, it does not support UTF-8.  Files that are not in a natively supported character set can be filtered through `iconv` first before passing them to `enscript`.

Comment: +1 for finding a report that old! I guess enscript isn't used much any more or someone would have fixed something as basic as this. I'll study the report and your code a bit before accepting your answer. Unfortunately, my script is part of a project, so I won't be able to ask other users to implement a patch like this as well.

Comment: @Joe The bug report was going for a more comprehensive solution.  By contrast, my `.hdr` file was aimed simply at allowing one to print footers _without_ any of the other changes suggested by the bug report.  No re-compile necessary.  If the other users cannot modify `/usr/share/enscript`, it is also possible to install the `simple2.hdr` file in `~/.enscript/'.

Comment: As for `enscript` being little used, that happened after CUPS chose a different text-to-ps converter.  I find, with one exception, that `enscript` is far more feature-full than what CUPS uses.  The exception is that `enscript` does not support UTF8.  In such cases, filter the text through `iconv` before passing it to `enscript`.

Comment: Thanks for the great information. It wasn't clear to me that your solution works without the patch. I use .enscriptrc. I didn't notice that .enscript is also available for the use you suggest. The enscript man page lists all those variables, but I didn't make the connection that you had to use them in custom header files.